# MySQL merging queries correctly

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a table to store messages with the following columns:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------+
| ID | parent_id | author_id | recipient_id | subject | body | created             | is_read |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------+------+---------------------+---------+
| 1  | 0         | 51        | 52           | sub1    | bod1 | 2017-08-24 15:49:29 |    0    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1         | 52        | 51           | NULL    | bod2 | 2017-08-24 15:52:29 |    0    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1         | 51        | 52           | NULL    | bod3 | 2017-08-24 15:55:29 |    0    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From this table I would like to extract:

- The **Subject** of each 'thread' (a thread has a `parent_id` of 0, replies have a NULL value for the subject)
- The **Created** date of the most recent message in the thread
- The number of **Unread** messages in the thread where the `recipient_id` is equal to the current user_id

For example:

**Recipient ID 51**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| subject | last_message_date_time | unread |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| sub1    | 2017-08-24 15:55:29    | 1      |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Recipient ID 52**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| subject | last_message_date_time | unread |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| sub1    | 2017-08-24 15:55:29    | 2      |
---------------------------------------------
```

I've written some individual queries but I'm struggling to put them all together with JOINS (51 being the current user ID):

**1. All threads for the current user (a thread has a parent_id of 0)**

```
SELECT m1.ID, m1.subject
FROM messages m1
WHERE (m1.author_id = 51 OR m1.recipient_id = 51)
    AND m1.parent_id = 0
```

**2. The timestamp of the last message in the thread**

```
SELECT MAX(m2.created) as last_message_time_date
FROM messages m2
WHERE (author_id = 51 OR recipient_id = 51)
```

**3. The number of unread messages where the curent user is not the author**

```
SELECT COUNT(m3.ID) as unread
FROM messages m3
WHERE recipient_id = 51
    AND is_read = 0
```

I got as far as this:

```
SELECT m1.ID, m1.subject, MAX(m2.created), COUNT(m3.ID)
FROM messages m1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT created, parent_id
    FROM messages ) AS m2
    ON m1.ID = m2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ID, parent_id
    FROM messages 
    WHERE recipient_id = 51 AND is_read = 0) AS m3
    ON (m1.ID = m3.parent_id OR m1.ID = m3.ID)
WHERE (m1.author_id = 51 OR m1.recipient_id = 51)
    AND m1.parent_id = 0
```

My issue is that the count is returning an incorrect value (more than it should). Any advice would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and the desired result ?

Comment: Certainly, I've updated my question with some example data. Many thanks.

Comment: could you also add your desired result ? whats the result you want from the query

Comment: Ha yep was just adding that as you commented :) Thanks again

Comment: a) If a message is "in a thread" when there is a chain of parent_ids to IDs, you need a CTE or recursive procedure for this query. b) What does "thread(-start messages) for the current user" mean? 1 is ids & subjects of thread-start messages sent or received by 51, which I suppose is what you mean. 2 is the time of the last message sent or received by 51, which is not necessarily the last message in any thread. 3 is the count of unread messages received by 51, not unread messages not sent by 51. c) None of the described or actual queries contribute to the query you're supposed to write.

Comment: So the current user has a specific ID, in this case 51. When a message thread is created it adds a message to the database with a parent_id of 0. Any subsequent replies have the parent_id set to the ID of the that first message.
I understand the queries I've posted don't return the expected results as they rely on the results from the previous query. For example you can't get the timestamp of the last message in the thread without knowing what the thread ID is. Hence the request for help joining the queries together.
Thank you for taking the time to offer your help and advice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificationsj. Please, edit your comments into your question. You say "the queries I've posted don't return the expected results as they rely on the results from the previous query" but I guess you mean something like, they don't return what you say they return and the queries are intended to be subqueries embedded in a big query. I expected the latter but still don't (yet) see how they or their specs can get you the result you want (but I'll look more). Suggest you try a more complex input example producing more complex output.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems `distinct` was the answer:

```
SELECT m1.ID, m1.subject, m2.author_id, MAX(m2.created) as last_message_date_time, COUNT(distinct m3.ID) as unread
FROM messages m1 

LEFT JOIN messages m2 
    ON (m1.ID = m2.parent_id OR m1.ID = m2.ID)

LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT ID, parent_id 
    FROM messages  
    WHERE is_read = 0 
        AND recipient_id = 51
    ) 
    AS m3 
    ON (m1.ID = m3.parent_id OR m1.ID = m3.ID)

WHERE (m1.author_id = 51 OR m1.recipient_id = 51) 
    AND m1.parent_id = 0

GROUP BY m1.ID
```

Still open to improvements/suggestions though :)

Comment: This query doesn't return the columns you specified. What do you claim is actually a solution? Here m2.author_id can have multiple rows per group, so you need to group on it or aggregate it--read about ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Two left joins not on keys sometimes is resolved by a unique in an aggregate but other times means you need the inner join of two left joins. Please read & act on [mcve]. Eg what is your MySQL version? Eg what are your constraints?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've created an SQL Fiddle to hopefully better show what I'm trying to do and how I've achieved it so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d3858/16
I've removed the author_id part as I've realised I don't need that in this query.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle & simplifying & I see there's a comment above. Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. Please put fiddle code & link also in your question.